ランダムに表示する→順番に直す
この９つをランダムに並べて表示し、その後にこの順番に直して表示するプログラムを作りたいです。教えてください。
["1-1","1-2","1-3","2-1","2-2","2-3","3-1","3-2","3-3"]

こんな感じです⬇
開始 [2-3,3-1,3-3,1-3,2-1,1-2,3-2,2-2,1-1]  # ←開始の時点ではランダム
終了 [1-1,1-2,1-3,2-1,2-2,2-3,3-1,3-2,3-3]  # ←終了の時点で並べかえられている

学校の課題で、sort()メソッド、sorted() 関数は使ってはいけないことになっています。
今まで試したこと
1から9の数字をランダムに並べかえ、それぞれの数に"1-1","1-2","1-3"，，，，，と代入していく

言語の記載がありませんので考え方を知りたいということでしょうか？

言語はPythonです

学校の課題であるならば、身近な人に質問することを優先してみてください。既に「sort 等を使わない」前提条件があるように、「習った範囲の知識で回答すること」を恐らく求めているはずですが、QAサイトの他人にはその前提条件 (あなたがどこまで理解して、何がわからないのか) がわかりません。

そうしてみます߹꒳​߹ありがとうございます

ランダムに順番に表示して最後に最初のリストになったら終了するということであれば以下のようにもできます。
import random

a=["1-1","1-2","1-3","2-1","2-2","2-3","3-1","3-2","3-3"]
while True:
    x=random.sample(a, len(a))
    print(f"{x}")
    if x == a:
        break

下記のドキュメントを参考にしました。
note,nkmk.me Pythonでリストの要素をシャッフル（random.shuffle, sample）
参考になれば幸いです

ありがとうございます！参考にしてみます！

下記のように配列に格納してから表示することもできます。
import random

a = ["1-1","1-2","1-3","2-1","2-2","2-3","3-1","3-2","3-3"]
for x in [random.sample(a, len(a)), a]:
    print(f"{x}")

random.sample(a, len(a))の部分を たろーさん の作成したランダムに並べ替えたリストに置き換えれば良いと思います。
ご参考までに。
追記）
ループ構造にする必要がなければ、下記のようにすればわかりやすいと思います。
※ 開始・終了の文字も表示するようにしました。
import random

a = ["1-1","1-2","1-3","2-1","2-2","2-3","3-1","3-2","3-3"]
print(f"開始 {random.sample(a, len(a))}")
print(f"{random.sample(a, len(a))}")
print(f"終了 {a}")

以上。

出題意図などの背景が分からないですが、こういうことでしょうか。
a = ["1-1", "1-2", "1-3", "2-1", "2-2", "2-3", "3-1", "3-2", "3-3"]
print(print(__import__("random").shuffle(b:=a.copy())or b)or a)

['2-2', '1-2', '2-3', '3-2', '3-1', '1-3', '3-3', '1-1', '2-1']
['1-1', '1-2', '1-3', '2-1', '2-2', '2-3', '3-1', '3-2', '3-3']


こういうことです！ありがとうございます！このプログラムってどういう仕組みになっているんですか？
